# AFNetworking perform background task only when wifi available

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, nsurlsession

I would like to use AFNetworking's `AFHTTPSessionManager` to implement a upload data action to a web server(e.g post action) only when Wifi is available and the action should be queued even if cellular network is available. I think I need to make use of `AFNetworkReachabilityManager`. But in AFNetworking's github, it only shows how to work with `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` and `manager.operationQueue`.

Hence, I want to ask if I can do the similar stuff using `AFHTTPSessionManager` and its `operationQueue`

the following is my thought with some code snippet, do it make sense to do so?

AppDelegate.m

```
@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURLSession *session;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableURLRequest *request;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AFHTTPSessionManager *manager;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [self config_sessionManager];
    [self config_request];

    return YES;
}

- (void)config_sessionManager {

    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:TargetURL];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:kSCIdenitifer];
    self.manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL sessionConfiguration:config];

    //actually, what is this operationQueue? I don't quit understand it
    //sometimes, I see `mainQueue` was used,
    //e.g `[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:op]` in GET example in the Github
    NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = self.manager.operationQueue;

    [self.manager.reachabilityManager setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
        switch (status) {
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
                [operationQueue setSuspended:NO];
                break;

            default:
                [operationQueue setSuspended:YES];
                break;
        }
    }];

    [self.manager.reachabilityManager startMonitoring];
}

- (void)config_request {
    self.request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kTargetURL]];
    self.request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    self.request.HTTPBody = [self.m_str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

- (void)run_task {

    NSURLSessionUploadTask * task = [self.manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:self.request progress:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            //ok, no error
            NSLog(@"upload data successfully!!!!");
        }
        else {
            //there is error
            NSLog(@"error with uploading data!!!!");
        }
    }];
    [task resume];

}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    [self run_task];
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}

@end
```

So, if I am doing like above, would I queue up the task `config_task` in the session manager if Wifi is not available? And if later Wifi is available again, would the task be resumed and the data as I want?